# Fill in a partiiton field with current date in PartitonRecord processor in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to partition records comes from Kafka based on date. For this purposes I use PartitionRecord processor with a dynamic property `partition_date` (every message has a property `created_at`). But some messages don't have `created_at` field (delete events).
So I need somehow to fill in `partition_date` attribute if `created_at` is Null.
I suppose I can use nifi expression language for it - if created_at is null then use {now()} else take date form message.
Could you suggest me how to create such expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UpdateAttribute` processor:

- `partition_date` (dynamic property): `${created_at:isNull():ifElse(${now()}, ${created_at})}`